# how can I disable the default email address style in an email?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm writing an email template using html table. And there is an email address in the content of this email template. When I sent out this email template to test it, It seems that gmail and yahoo mail always add some default style to the email address in the email content, which will make it a blue, underlined, clickable link. But I don't want these style. I just want the email address to be shown as pure text as others. So how should I get rid of these default style for email address?

Answer (score 2):

Usually I will just make it my own link, and style it inline to match the text.

```
<a href="mailto:email@address.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:#0a0a0a;">email@address.com</a>
```

Some email clients will also ignore `#ffffff` and `#000000` as link colors so, you can substitute with a slightly off version of your desired color.

Comment: This also works for phone numbers. Wrap a href around them to stop them becoming a blue phone link

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.  gmail and yahoo add this styling in the client, to make life easier for their users.  I don't think there's any way that you can override that without mangling the email address in some way, like adding spaces either side of the `@` and `.` characters.